# VBA to Refresh Power Query does not allow enough time to Refresh Queries upon save and close

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

We have 185 files in a directory that need to be updated. There are two Power Queries and neither of them will refresh whilst using the code below. Also worth mentioning, if I open each individual file, the first query will update, but the second one will not. I will have to Refresh All. These files are highly classified and I cannot have one of the files not update thus releasing records to another salesperson. These files were supposed to go out tomorrow 11/15/23 and I am stuck. Please help! I have tried Refresh all as well.

```
Sub UpdatePowerQuery()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog


'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  'Bypasses the Update Links
  Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
  MsgBox "WARNING: Make sure you pick the correct folder!"
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
      
    'Code between lines is performed on each workbook in the folder
    
    '************************************************************************
  WB.Queries.FastCombine = True 'ignores privacy levels on all computers
  
  WB.Connections("Query - SF Data").Refresh
  WB.Connections("Query - SF Data Totals").Refresh
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))
   
    
    '************************************************************************
    'Save and Close Workbook
      WB.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

'sourceBook.Close

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is "Background Refresh" enabled? If so try disabling it. https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/enable-background-refresh-on-all-power-query-connections/